# Check if a dict key is in a list (tuple) of dict

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm using the following example to check if an item is in a list:

```
var = 'a'
var_list = ('a','b','c')
if var in var_list:
  do_something()
```

But in my case, what I have is a dictionary and a list of dictionaries:

```
var = {'name': 'John', 'age': 35, 'city': 'Orlando'}
var_list = ( {'name': 'John', 'age': 36, 'city': 'Orlando'} , \
             {'name': 'Alex', 'age': 22, 'city': 'New York'} , \
             {'name': 'Celes', 'age': 24, 'city': 'Vector'} )
if var['name'] in var_list:
  do_something()
```

I need to only check the key 'name' in the comparasion, otherwise if I do `var in var_list` the key `age` will be different and will result in not getting inside the if condition. Is it possible to compare only the `name` key?

Of course, I can iterate and check item by item, but if there is a function or something that will reduce the execution time, it will be great.

Comment: Nop, there's no magic method. Iteration is the way to go.

Comment: @khelwood You meant `var['name'] == x['name']`?

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Yeah probably

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
if var['name'] in [d['name'] for d in var_list]:
    doSomething()
```

Comment: It would be better to use a generator instead of a list to short-circuit as soon as a match is found.

Answer (score 2):

One way is to test versus a set of names from your list of dictionaries.

```
from operator import itemgetter as iget

name_set = set(map(iget('name'), var_list))

if var['name'] in name_set:
    do_something()
```

Comment: Using a `set` isn't going to improve anything in this case, because set creation itself will result in a full-loop.

Comment: It's not an optimization for one lookup, but it's useful if this is going to be done multiple times. In fact, I'll make this a separate step to emphasize the fact.

Answer (score 1):

You can use builtin function [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) to check if there is a match. It will return boolean `True` or `False` based on whether the value is matched or not.

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> any(var['name'] == k for k in map(itemgetter('name'),var_list))
>>> True
```

However if you are interested in actual matched element you can do it with following generator expression:

```
>>> next((item for item in var_list if item["name"] == var["name"]),None)
>>> {'name': 'John', 'age': 36, 'city': 'Orlando'}
```